# How to solve 500 Internet Service error usign SoapUI

Tags: web, web-scraping, soap, wsdl, soapui

I am facing some issue in soap UI . I have imported wsdl file and submit the request but it is throwing an error . fault code - Receiver, fault string - Unknown error and status - 500 Internet service error?

This is the request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:dictionary:com.chargepoint.webservices">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-A6CBF48C2D9DBB6D1416050783694892">
        <wsse:Username>0dac5f009a1531993ea851fa7f529ac15fa95a45a2cb41604934213</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">7bbdb8f46ba21a24418a87940393cbad</wsse:Password>
        <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">pj2N9pLhDSyVtnNM7yOXnQ==</wsse:Nonce>
        <wsu:Created>2020-11-11T07:06:09.489Z</wsu:Created>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
      <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-A6CBF48C2D9DBB6D1416050746317081">
        <wsu:Created>2020-11-11T06:03:51.704Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2020-11-11T06:13:51.704Z</wsu:Expires>
      </wsu:Timestamp>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <urn:getChargingSessionData> 45 35 asv tyy hk ap IN 67 56 1 2013-02-13T14:08:36Z 2013-02-13T14:08:36Z 56 102 45 </urn:getChargingSessionData>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Have you checked that the XML is well-formed? Could you please provide a sample? Does the endpoint service require authentication? You can check reposnse headers on _Headers_ tab, under service response section to review some authentication parameters.

Comment: its well formed and yes endpoint need authentication which is already done

Comment: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:dictionary:com.chargepoint.webservices">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-A6CBF48C2D9DBB6D1416050783694892">
            <wsse:Username>0dac5f009a1531993ea851fa7f529ac15fa95a45a2cb41604934213</wsse:Username>

Comment: Hi, @tarun. Please, avoid send pieces of code as comments. Instead, update your post with the code, properly identified.

Comment: Thanks, @tarun. I added some formatting, to make it easier to read.

Comment: ok thanks @DaveMiller . any luck on the solution

Comment: Please, check this link, as the problem described seems similar to yours, you may find something useful: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49964/magento-api-soap-v2-faultcode-receiver-faultstring-uknown-error